# Intercept the id or the command of a Rollback process in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, information-schema

Is it possible to find the process ID or the command that is executed for a rollback ?

More specifically :

The `Information_Schema` of MySQL has a specific table named `processlist`. This contains the details about every ongoing process in MySQL. An example of the table looks like this:

```
mysql> select * from processlist;
+----+------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+------------+---------------------------+
| ID | USER | HOST      | DB                 | COMMAND | TIME | STATE      | INFO                      |
+----+------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+------------+---------------------------+
|  5 | root | localhost | information_schema | Query   |    5 | User sleep | select sleep(20)          |
|  4 | root | localhost | information_schema | Query   |    0 | executing  | select * from processlist |
+----+------+-----------+--------------------+---------+------+------------+---------------------------+
```

Is it possible for me to intercept a Rollback and grab its `ID` or `INFO` from this table ? The issue I have been facing is that any Rollback I execute gets completed before I am able to intercept its `ID` from the Table.

Comment: The only thing I can think of here would be to somehow add logic which can detect an error in your stored proc, and then log some appropriate information.  Upvoted +1.

Comment: I also fiddled with the concept of having a different mysql user call a rollback on a huge table , but that doesnt seem like a practical approach.

Comment: Are you using an app language (e.g. Java) to make your MySQL calls?  If so, you  might be able to manage the transaction from there.

Comment: I am using Java, more specifically Spring Framework. My primary interest isn't Transaction Management ,I can do that with the tools already available. I am trying to simulate interrupting an ongoing rollback to ascertain the command/Info used for it, no existing tool allows me to kill/interrupt a rollback because it violates ACID property.